# Measuring typical distance between patches using 2D Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, data-analysis, signal-processing, correlation-functions, image-processing

I need to extract information about the typical distance between the black patches in an image like the one I attached here. I tried to perform 2D FFT on it (using OpenCF fdt function in Python), but I am not sure if this is the best way to do this job. Anyone has an idea what is the method that I need to use to perform this job? I have read about two-point correlation function in astronomy, but I wonder if it can be used also in this case..
[image: Image for analysis]

Comment: I think this is a good question, but perhaps better suited to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I reckon that the part of the question regarding the problem of measurement of a typical distance between object is still physics or astronomy, don't you think? In any case I will post the image processing part of the question on dsp. Thanks for the tip!